# Integer roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, integers

I have a polynomial with integer coefficients on the form

$$ p_{l,N}(x) = x^{2l+1} - 2\sum_{m=0}^{l}\binom{2l+1}{2m}x^{2m}\sum_{j=1}^N j^{2l+1-2m} $$

and I am interested in finding the possible integer roots of this with $l\in\mathbb{N}:l\geq 1$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}:l\geq 1$. I think I was able to show that for specified values of $N$ and $l$, there is only one real root. In addition, if the root is integer, it must be an even number.

I guess one can use the *integral root theorem* to reduce the possible solutions to be factors of

$$2\sum_{j=1}^N j^{2l+1}$$

Am I right? If so, is there a way to find the factors of such a power sum in general? Thanks in advance for any help on this.